# What we are actually doing with property in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

First of all I am very new in Objective C and iOS development.

Currently I am trying to use TableView

I have property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;//for table view
```

Now I seen something like this,

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [data count];
}
```

What is exact meaning of the code. What I am doing with `tableView` here, and how name of **property** and name of **message** is same, i.e. `tableView`.

Comment: You can learn this and many other things from official Stanford University iOS programming lectures which you can find in iTunes. I think it's the best way to know the basics (more complicated examples may be outdated) if you are learning by yourself. I did it that way and it helped a lot.

Comment: @cyborg86pl Thanks I will go through it.

Comment: Please start by learning something about Objective-C first, the purpose of this site is answering specific questions - not teaching programming languages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am doing with tableView here

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is a method from the [UITableViewDatasource Protocole](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to do simple, the object of type `UITableView` will do something like it :

```
[self.delegate tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:section]
```

and so, if you do `tableView.datasource = self` in your `viewController`, it's this object which will receive the message and so, need to answer to the `tableview`.

> and how name of property and name of message is same, i.e. tableView.

`@property` is just an indication for the compiler to create accessors and iVar in your class, that why it seems to do many things at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In first line you are declaring property of an tableview which you create by storyboard.

The goal of the `@property` directive is to make it easy to create and configure properties by automatically generating these accessor methods. It allows you to specify the behavior of a public property on a semantic level, and it takes care of the implementation details for you.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
return [data count];
}
```

This is a tableview delegate method which define the no of row in a particular section in table view

data is your array name contain element which you want to show in tableview cell

`[data count]` return the number of row in your table view

for more detail check

[property](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html)

[table view](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)